# how to incrementally update an array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

suppose there were 3 random arrays:

```
A = np.random.rand( 100 )
B = np.random.rand( 100 )
C = np.random.choice( 100, size=100 )
```

what I was trying to do is like below:

```
V = np.zeros( 100 )
while True:
    v = V.copy()
    V = A * ( B + V[ C ] )
    if np.abs( V - v ).max() < 1e-9:
        break
```

the problem is, in each iteration of the while loop, each components of V, is not updated in place.

for example, when calculating V[10], it may require the value of V[5], but at that time, V[5] is of old value which was generated at last iteration, not the newest value generated at this iteration.

this leads to much more loops and sometimes even not workable situation.

to be more accurate, the effect i'm trying to implement is like below:

```
V = np.zeros( 100 )
while True:
    v = V.copy()

    for index in range( len( V ) ):
        V[index] = A[index] * ( B[index] + V[ C[index] ] )

    if np.abs( V - v ).max() < 1e-9:
        break
```

but in a vectorized way.

any method to solve this problem? thank you!

Comment: How do you decide the order with which V shall be upated. If V[10] needs V[5] and V[5] needs V[10] (which can happen), how do you decide which of these shall get the "old" and which the "new" value?

Comment: Yes, with the compiled `numpy` operations (and Python in general) the RHS is evaluated in full before assignment to the left.  `V = fun(V)` is fully buffered.  Element by element iteration in Python should produce the values you want, but be much slower.  Or you could compile this operation with `numba` or `cython`.

Comment: @Jan Christoph Terasa, from row 0 to row 99.

Comment: @hpaulj any numpy or even pandas tricks for this? I have to use cpython

Comment: If the value v[1] depends on v[0], there is nothing to vectorize. You can only try to speed up the loop using the mentioned methods, i.e, moving the loop out of interpreted Python code.

Comment: any numpy or pandas tricks?@Jan Christoph Terasa